# What is the meaning of this math formulation?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, integer-programming, gurobi, vehicle-routing

I have been wondering what is the meaning of this sigma with delta negative or plus in there (if my read is correct).

$$
\sum_{i \in \Delta^{-}(j)} x_{i j k}-\sum_{i \in \Delta^{+}(j)} x_{j i k}=0 \quad \forall k \in K, j \in N
$$

Comment: from the paper : https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9648591

Comment: or can refer to toth, and vigo, Vehicle Routing Problem with Time Windows

Answer (score 3):

The set of equations are used to represent the conservation of flow at every node $j$ in a network. Here, $\Delta^{-}(j)$ represents the set of nodes coming into node $j$ and  $\Delta^{+}(j)$ represents the set of nodes coming out of node $j$.